# Showing $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k/10^{k!}$ is not rational

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> If $(a_k)_{k=1}^\infty\subset \mathbb{N}$ with $1\leq a_k\leq 9$ for all $k$ and if $\alpha=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{10^{k!}}$ then $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

I tried to prove this statement by contradiction i.e., $\alpha=\frac{c}{d}$ where $c\in \mathbb{Z}, d\in\mathbb{N}$. I tried to use the fact that $10^{(n-1)!}\geq10^{n-1}>n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. However, I could not reach a contradiction. So any help is appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: This is proved in many number theory textbooks, or the [Wikipedia article on Liouville numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number).

Comment: What do you think a contradiction is going to come from?